# How to display newly created simple products inside the configurable product's Associate product grid in Magento 2.4.4?

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product, magento2.4.4, associated-products

I'm using Magento 2.4.4 version in which I need to assign a newly created simple product inside the configurable product using the "Add Products Manually", however, the same newly created simple products are not displaying inside the configurable product's Associate product grid.

Is anyone else facing the same issue?

Any help/suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Newly created product might not visible inside the add products grid because they might not in same configurations like if your configurable product have size and color variation then same variation should came in newly added simple products. Otherwise you have to assign/tell configurable product that new variation is came.

If you wanted to upload products by csv then arrange the SKU as per attached image in .csv file and your simple variations will came with configurable product. (Arrange Properly Red/Green/Blue Marked Column's value)

[image]